# C#: Bug in ComboBox when items are UserControls?

Tags: c#, winforms, string, user-controls, combobox

I am adding objects from classes which are derived from UserControl to a ComboBox control. This is really helpful as I can access the necessary control directly from the combobox.
It all works fine EXCEPT for the fact that all ComboBox entries are empty strings (the derived UserControls behind it are fully accessible using selectedItem)...
The ComboBox uses DropDownList as its drop down style - but changing that doesn't fix it.

A minimum working example displaying empty strings:

```
public class TestControl : UserControl {
    public override string toString(){
        return "Example";
    }
}

...
combobox.Items.Add(new TestControl());
...
```

When I call

```
combobox.Items.Add(new TestControl().ToString());
```

directly, the entry is "Example".

Is this a bug in the ComboBox control or am I doing something wrong?
Thank you

Comment: I am sure it is just a typo, but it should be `ToString` with an uppercase `T`.

Comment: yes, of course, it is ToString() - just a typo, just as SelectedItem

Comment: I am not understanding this question...Are you or aren't you getting the value Example?

Comment: @Sebastian is the `ToString()` in the Control capitalized as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Odd, that should work. Another alternative would be to set the DisplayMember property of the combobox to a property on your TestControl:

> Typically, the representation of an object in the ComboBox is the
>   string returned by that object's ToString method. If you want to have
>   a member of the object displayed instead, choose the member that will
>   be displayed by setting the DisplayMember property to the name of the
>   appropriate member.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.items.aspx (in the remarks section)

Comment: Stuart Dunkeld, bemused: Thank you very much. I unfortunately can't get the DisplayMember workaround to work: I first set the DataSource property and then I set DisplayMember to "name". Is this the correct way of doing this? I am still getting empty entries. Thanks.

Comment: Wow, thanks guys! I got it to work, didn't have getters and setters. But still a bug, though...

Comment: The standard value a UserControl displays when invoking ToString() on it, is its fully qualified name (namespace and so on...). Makes it even more curious :)