# Why overriden ToString() do not return what I want when item added to ComboBox?

Tags: c#, combobox, overriding, tostring

```
public partial class TestConrol : UserControl
{
    public TestConrol()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "asd";
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TestConrol tc1 = new TestConrol();
        comboBox1.Items.Add(tc1);

        TestConrol tc2 = new TestConrol();
        comboBox1.Items.Add(tc2);
    }
}
```

When form loaded, I see combobox has two items with empty names, instead of "asd" :/
But this work if I override ToString() in common class, not derived from anything:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "bla bla bla";
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TestClass tcl = new TestClass();
        comboBox1.Items.Add(tcl);
    }
}
```

After that I see in combobox "bla bla bla"

Comment: Where are you calling `ToString()` look at this site for an example / explanation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: it should be called by combobox when item added, like it work for common classes

Comment: Could you perhaps do a `Protected override on one of the comboboxes properties, accessing it from the e.argument(s) params?`

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what you telling :(

Comment: never mind I was thinking more or less overriding on one of the events where the data is being changed `On Change Event` but you could also do the same thing based on what was also suggested in the answer below in regards to creating a `Property`

Comment: I see the same behavior. It looks like the internal code of `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox` uses the `ToString` override only for objects that are not `System.Windows.Forms.UserControl`.

Comment: See also [C#: Bug in ComboBox when items are UserControls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846507/c-bug-in-combobox-when-items-are-usercontrols).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to understand the source code(!). This is not a simple call to `ToString()`.

There's an `internal` class `System.Windows.Forms.Formatter` doing some stuff. It eventually creates a converter. This is roughly equivalent to saying:

```
var conv = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(tc1.GetType());
```

where `tc1` is the `TestContol` from your question. Now, had we used the `TestClass` `tcl` which doesn't implement any interfaces, this would have given us a converter which would eventually call `ToString()`.

But in this example we use `tc1`, and it is a [`System.ComponentModel.IComponent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icomponent.aspx). Our `conv` therefore becomes a `System.ComponentModel.ComponentConverter`. It uses the `Site` of the `IComponent`. When we say:

```
string result = conv.ConvertTo(tc1, typeof(string));
```

and the `Site` is null, we get the empty string `""` you saw in your combo box. Had there been a `Site` it would have used its `Name` instead.

To demonstrate that, put the following into your `TestControl` instance constructor:

```
public TestConrol()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Site = new DummySite(); // note: Site is public, so you can also
                            // write to it from outside the class.
                            // It is also virtual, so you can override
                            // its getter and setter.
}
```

where `DummySite` is something like:

```
class DummySite : ISite
{
    public IComponent Component
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public IContainer Container
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public bool DesignMode
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return "asd";  // HERE'S YOUR TEXT
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. Your answer worth to be accepted, since it really answers on "why overriden ToString() ..."

Comment: Ah, I guess that's why they say in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z819d1t5.aspx) of `Component.ToString` that it shouldn't be overridden.

Comment: I appreciate your level and understanding.  Thanks for your insightful answer!

Answer (score 5):

Create a property in you control and map the DisplayMember of the combobox to that property, it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I trying that... But for weird reason when I click to chose DisplayingMember in properties list, it empty, so nothing to choose

Comment: Ohh, I just need to type there, instead of choose. Now it work, thank you!

Comment: Ohh Ohh but what to do with CheckedListBox? :D there is no DisplayingMember, but same issue

Comment: yes there is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx

Comment: Huh weird, I don't see this in PropertyList

Comment: Also, IntelliSence do not show it in object too... I type checkedListBox1.Dis... control + space = no DisplayMember :(

Comment: Brrr maybe VS bugs. I typed it manually checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "something"; and it's OK. Thanks for everything

Answer (score 1):

Use `comboBox1.Items.Add(tc1.ToString());` instead of `comboBox1.Items.Add(tcl);`

Comment: I kinda want to be able to cast comboBox1.SelectedItem back to class instance... P.S. -1 is not mine :P Still thanks for answer, it could help if question was asked by newbie

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `UserControl`, add a property, and call it `FriendlyName` for example, as such

```
namespace project
{
   public partial class CustomUserControl : UserControl
   {
      public CustomUserControl()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      public String FriendlyName { get => "Custom name"; }
   }
}
```

And then set the `DisplayMember` property of your `ComboBox` to **"FriendlyName"**, as such

```
myComboBox.DisplayMember = "FriendlyName";
```

And to me, this was a very clean solution and gut tells me it is the intended way to do it.